# Digital Asset Link verification fails sporadically. Unable to draw any pattern of failure

Tags: android, digital-assets-links

We have to load a third party HTML file on our Android application [custom chrome tab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/overview/). To access the file the third party requires our application to pass (Non-Whitelisted)request headers in the request to download the HTML file.

We have utilized the solution described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/headers/)

We see no issues on our development environments but on production we notice that the asset link verification fails randomly and we are not able to draw any pattern of failure. Some observations below

1. There is no failure for any specific version of Android or Chrome
2. There is no delay or issue in accessing the digital asset link file
3. 2 users with the exact same Android phone model and configurations notice that the asset verification fails on one device and not the other
4. Even on the same Android device, 2 separate requests to verify asset link file have different behaviours. With one failing and the other succeeding.

Since the asset link verification fails, chrome tab issues the request without the request headers and the download fails.

The only pattern we have been able to draw is that this happens whenever we release a new version of the Android application. The issue persists for about 3-4 days after which we don't see the issue happen anymore.

**Queries**

1. How does Google Asset link verification occur under the hood and any guidance on how we can debug further?
2. The only other alternative we see is to use WebViews which we would like to avoid if possible. Is there any other alternative?

**Details**

As per the solution example above we have the something similar to this

```
CustomTabsCallback callback = new CustomTabsCallback() {
@Override
public void onRelationshipValidationResult(int relation, @NonNull Uri requestedOrigin, 
    boolean result, @Nullable Bundle extras) {
    // Launch custom tabs intent after session was validated as the same origin.
    CustomTabsIntent intent = constructExtraHeadersIntent(mSession);
    intent.launchUrl(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse(url));
}
```

We notice that the boolean argument *result* is returned false on some occasions.